# Не могу получить значение div'a методом .val()(При val() - выдает пустую строку) или .value(при value выдает undefined)

Tags: html, jquery

Вот html:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

jquery:

```
$("docement").ready(function () {

    $(".close").on("click",function (e) {
var el = $(this).parent().children(".kek");
console.log(el.val());



    });
})
```

И причем даже если я убираю свойство hidden, то все равно не показывает значение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Атрибут `type="hidden"` (как и свойство `value`) не имеет смысла для элемента `div`.

```
var el = $(this).closest(".deserve").find(".kek");
console.log(el.text());
```

или

```
<input type="hidden" class="kek" value="3" />
```

---

P.S. `$("docement")` -> `$("document")`

Answer (score 0):

В описании [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) ясно указано, что он применяется для получения значений элементов формы, таких как `input`, `select` и `textarea`. При применении к другим элементам будет идти попытка получить значение свойства `value`. У элемента `div` это свойство отсутствует.

Вместо этого можно воспользоваться методом [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) либо [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

---

Если очень хочется использовать именно `val`, можно добавить `valHooks` для элементов `div`

```js
jQuery.valHooks.div = {
  get: function(el) {
    return el.textContent;
  }
};

var el = $('#d');
console.log(el.val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d">div value</div>
```